# MobaXTerm issues with opening sessions and ppk passwords

Tags: ssh, rdp, mobaxterm

I currently got a RDP-Server set up and tried to connect to it via VPC and MobaXTerm.

When getting asked for the password for the private key by MobAgent, I entered the password I saved for it, but that didn't work as I got asked the same question again immediately. The window only disappeared when I left the space empty and clicked on the "ok" button.

Then, after connections without a Jumphost didn't work as planned, I set up one that included a Jumphost, but now MobaXTerm won't start that session while still opening older sessions. Restarting MobaXTerm and Windows didn't help, so now I'm at my wits' end.

Could someone please help me here? What do I need to do for MobaXTerm to accept my password and to successfully open all sessions?

Or does someone know a good alternative to MobaXTerm for RDP-connections?

Regarding the first issue: the Public keys are included in the authorized_keys-file and the private keys are in the MobaXTerm-.ssh-directory, so that shouldn't be the issue. But then again, the public keys were much shorter than the ones already in the authorized_keys-file, so could that be an indicator of the issue?